# Qt5.7 qmake; what does "The system cannot find the path specified." mean and how to fix it?

Tags: qt, qmake, qt5.7

Qt5.7/mingw/windows8.1 qmake. New installation. when i run qmake on a project file, i get the above error message, although the makefiles are emitted, they build and the project works (it would seem).

running qmake from the command line; here are the paths i added to PATH:

`I:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\bin;i:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin;I:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin`

Is this something to do with config files or caches? If so, where would these be. Also is there any other external state that qmake requires.

thanks.

EDIT#1 
here is the project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick quickcontrols2
CONFIG += console

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

Edit #2: output from QtCreator 4.0.2

general messages tab:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Compile output tab, run qmake:

```
14:49:57: Running steps for project Q1...
14:49:57: Starting: "I:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" I:\larry\qt\q9edit\Q1.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
14:49:57: The process "I:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
14:49:57: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Compile output, rebuild:

```
14:51:32: Running steps for project Q1...
14:51:32: Starting: "I:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" clean
I:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug clean
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'I:/larry/qt/q9edit'
rm -f debug/qrc_qml.cpp
rm -f debug/main.o debug/qrc_qml.o
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'I:/larry/qt/q9edit'
I:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release clean
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'I:/larry/qt/q9edit'
rm -f release/qrc_qml.cpp
rm -f release/main.o release/qrc_qml.o
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'I:/larry/qt/q9edit'
14:51:33: The process "I:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
14:51:33: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
14:51:33: Starting: "I:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
I:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'I:/larry/qt/q9edit'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICKCONTROLS2_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtQuickControls2 -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtQuick -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtGui -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtANGLE -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtQml -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtNetwork -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtCore -Idebug -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o debug/main.o main.cpp
'I:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\rcc.exe' -name qml qml.qrc -o debug/qrc_qml.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICKCONTROLS2_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtQuickControls2 -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtQuick -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtGui -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtANGLE -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtQml -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtNetwork -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtCore -Idebug -I../../../Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o debug/qrc_qml.o debug/qrc_qml.cpp
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug/Q1.exe debug/main.o debug/qrc_qml.o  -LI:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/lib I:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/lib/libQt5QuickControls2d.a I:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/lib/libQt5Quickd.a I:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/lib/libQt5Guid.a I:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/lib/libQt5Qmld.a I:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/lib/libQt5Networkd.a I:/Qtmg/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/lib/libQt5Cored.a 
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'I:/larry/qt/q9edit'
14:51:34: The process "I:\Qtmg\Qt5.7.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
14:51:34: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

Comment: That problem may also depend on your project file. You should provide some more information, like the fully build log.

Comment: added project file. there a log? where would it be, thanks.

Comment: In Qt Creator there are some views at the bottom, one showing the build problems where your error message might be found and one for compiler output (beside some others). The compiler output would be interesting.

Comment: added outputs as suggested,

Answer (score 2):

Try editing your changes to the PATH variable, to remove one directory at a time. Looks to me like you are trying to add an unnecessary path (unnecessary since the build succeeds) that is not present on your system.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Following up this idea, it appears that i have _another_ copy of mingw installed (after the qt paths), and qmake searches for `sh.exe`, which it find in this other installation.

What's weird is that it searches for `sh.exe` when there is no such binary in the qt install directories. If i prevent it from finding `sh.exe` it will generates a `.qmake.stash` file whereafter it will use this to run make regardless of the paths. None of this stash file refers to the other mingw though.

Comment: If the answer is correct, can you please mark it as such? Thanks.